# filterxml function in excel 2013 returns #value! error

Tags: xml, xpath

The XML below returns an error value when filtered in excel 2013 using the filterxml function
the xpath that I specified in the filterxml function is =FILTERXML(A3,"//DataSet/diffgr:diffgram/NewDataSet/Rates/Display"). I need help figuring out what I did wrong. Thank you.

```
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">

  <xs:complexType>

    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">

      <xs:element name="Rates">

        <xs:complexType>

          <xs:sequence>

            <xs:element name="Quote" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

            <xs:element name="Display" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />

            <xs:element name="UpdateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />

          </xs:sequence>

        </xs:complexType>

      </xs:element>

    </xs:choice>

  </xs:complexType>

</xs:element>
```

```
<NewDataSet xmlns="">

  <Rates diffgr:id="Rates1" msdata:rowOrder="0">

    <Quote>AUD/CAD</Quote>

    <Display>0.97544/94</Display>

    <UpdateTime>2013-11-13T00:19:26.307-05:00</UpdateTime>

  </Rates>

  <Rates diffgr:id="Rates2" msdata:rowOrder="1">

    <Quote>AUD/CHF</Quote>

    <Display>0.85280/30</Display>

    <UpdateTime>2013-11-13T00:19:11.182-05:00</UpdateTime>

  </Rates>

  <Rates diffgr:id="Rates3" msdata:rowOrder="2">

    <Quote>AUD/JPY</Quote>

    <Display>92.540/70</Display>

    <UpdateTime>2013-11-13T00:19:26.307-05:00</UpdateTime>

  </Rates>

  <Rates diffgr:id="Rates4" msdata:rowOrder="3">

    <Quote>AUD/NZD</Quote>

    <Display>1.13019/79</Display>

    <UpdateTime>2013-11-13T00:19:10.838-05:00</UpdateTime>

  </Rates>

</NewDataSet>
```